# no "top link bar" available ALTHOUGH "Publishing" is disabled

Tags: publishing, top-link-bar

I have sharepoint 2010 and I experience problems with the "top link bar" - it is simply not available under "look and feel" options (there is a "navigation" instead).

I've read on a variety of sites that I need to disable the "SharePoint Server Publishing" to enable the "top link bar". That's what I did - for sure - but the "top link bar" is still not available.. how is it possible? What do I do to get the "top link bar" back to work?

Comment: Did you disable it for the site collection?

Answer (score 3):

Even though top link was missing from settings, by adding `/_layouts/15/topnav.aspx` to your site URL you can open it

`https://xxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxxxxx/_layouts/15/topnav.aspx`

Answer (score 2):

Not only "SharePoint Server Publishing" should be disabled, but under "Site Collection Features" you have to deactivate "**SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**" also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable both features like "SharePoint Server Publishing" and  "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure". Definitely, it will be visible(Top link bar). Because it is a default feature so Once you activate the publishing feature by default the Top link bar feature will be disabled.